# Are hilbert spaces invariant under gauge transformations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, gauge-invariance

I'm trying to work out if the physical hilbert space is invariant under any gauge transformation? I have found situations where under some transformations they don't change but I've now gotten very confused through what appear to be conflicting arguments.

My understanding of the hilbert space is that it is the space generated by acting the creation operator on the vacuum state and I'm not sure that the creation operator should depend on the gauge, so does that mean it is invariant?

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: $\uparrow$ Found situations in which references?

Comment: It is not clear what are the "gauge transformations" you have problems with. However, from your second paragraph, it seems you are worrying about states like $a^\dagger|0\rangle$ being not gauge-invariant because one can redefine $a^\dagger$ by a phase. For a state this has no effect, since a state in a Hilbert space is always defined up to an overall phase and you can not detect the "phase" by any physical measurements.

Comment: A Hilbert space is just a complete (possible infinite dimensional) linear space with a scalar product (that induces the norm), nothing more! In QM we use complex Hilbert spaces. If the gauge transformation did non leave the Hilbert space intact, it could not be formulated for vectors in this Hilbert space. Well, whether a gauge transformation leaves linear subspaces invariant, that you can ask. The kind of space you are referring to is a Fock space, which is a special kind of Hilbert space used in many particle physics.